# Recover passwords protected by Master Password in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, password-recovery

I know my Master Password. How can I revocer particualr password eg. for android .apk signing?
Now, when I want to sign .apk just enter Master Password and key stores passwords fields filled automatically.
I forgot these passwords in plain text, can I read them from IntelliJ password database?

Comment: I'm in the same situation as you. Did you manage to recover the passwords?

Comment: It's ridiculous, but finally I guessed my password back. :)

Comment: Thanks. Good for you, I'm still stuck :)

Comment: it starts with i3b5... just a trace for myself in the future ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no official instructions how to do that, however you still can do it programatically. Take a look at the sources for the details: https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/platform/platform-tests/testSrc/com/intellij/ide/passwordSafe/impl/providers/masterKey/MasterKeyPasswordSafeTest.java

Comment: The link is now broken.