# Intellij IDEA - view saved password

Tags: android, intellij-idea, passwords, keystore

I forgot the password for my Android keystore, but it's saved in the Intellij IDEA password manager. I know the master password, so IDEA is able to auto complete the keystore password, but I can find no way to view or copy/paste the password from the text field.

Is there a plugin that can do that, maybe?

I've also tried to look for some logs or a shell, because I assume that behind the scenes IDEA is using the `keytool` utility from the SDK, so maybe I can spot the password in the command line.

I've ran out of ideas. Please help.

EDIT: If anyone knows where the encrypted passwords are kept, I could back up the file and use it in future IDEA installations with the same master password. Would that work?

Comment: Similar issue for reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21006690/recover-passwords-protected-by-master-password-in-intellij-idea

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I've managed to understand the source code enough to put together a small utility program to decrypt the passwords in the security.xml file using the master password.
https://github.com/corneliudascalu/intellij-decrypt

Comment: Thank you so much, a life saver!

Comment: security.xml is found in C:\Users\{user}\{intellij.folder}\config\options\security.xml

Comment: On mac, the file is located here: ~/Library/Preferences/IntelliJIdea2016.2/options/security.xml

Comment: Super helpful. Recovered my old password starting with i3b5

Answer (score 31):

Note that for recent versions of IntelliJ on MacOS, the passwords are (likely) stored in the Keychain by default.

This can be verified via Preferences/Appearance & Behaviour/System Settings/Passwords.

The corresponding entries can be found via searching the keychain for "IntelliJ Platform DB" where they are listed by uuid.  The data sources for each uuid can be found in .idea/dataSources.xml

Comment: For newer IntelliJ versions on MacOS, the global data sources can be found at `~/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2020.3/options/dataSources.xml`, adjusted for the actual version number of course.

Comment: Applicable for Ubuntu as well. Found it in Password & Keys

Comment: It's been almost 2 years since this answer. Maybe JetBrains should add this to Intellij Idea documentation https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/reference-ide-settings-password-safe.html
I have given them feedback using the link on their page let's see if it gets there.

Answer (score 20):

For anyone attempting keystore password recovery on more recent versions of Android Studio and Ubuntu, it seems that most documented suggestions to recover the password from logs, gradle, etc no longer work. Corneliu's excellent brute force script is great - unless you chose a 16 character password with no dictionary words in it and would like a result some time this month :) Using the Intellij security.xml solution is no longer available to retrieve saved passwords from Android Studio either.

However - having dug around a bit, Android Studio 3.1 seems to use the OS keychain in Ubuntu 18.04, so retrieving a saved keystore password is as simple as:

1. open 'Passwords and Keys' (use super key and search 'password')
2. filter results by 'android'
3. look at each entry, they will be
   something like org.jetbrains.android...KeyPassowrdRequestor, and
   open each one up in turn
4. expand the password dropdown and select
   'Show password', it will look something like:
   KEY_STORE_PASSWORD__/home/pathto/keystore/keystore-name.jks@mycoolpassword

Find the keystore you're looking for and **the bit after** `@` **is your missing password**. Hope that helps someone out there!

Comment: Just in case someone accidentally stumbles in the same issue, for Mac user, open `Keychains` and search for jetbrains, same approach as yours. Peace out.

Comment: You are a lifesaver!

Comment: It works also for `Datagrip`, but for `Datagrip` name of each key/password has `IntelliJ Platform DB` phrase in it. Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

## Accessing saved database passwords for JetBrains products

I am accessing DataSource passwords for DataGrip but this should work for any JetBrains product like IntelliJ. The confusing part was that all information I could find specified that a Master Password was required to decrypt these passwords, but I never set a master password. You can actually decrypt your passwords by using a Master Password set afterwards.

### Getting the passwords

1. Open your JetBrain product's settings Password settings. Settings > Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Passwords
2. Your passwords should be saved in a .kdbx file (ex. C:/Users/<USER>/<JETBRAINS_PRODUCT>/config/c.kdbx)
3. Select the 3 dots to the right of this file and set your master password (if it's already set then you can keep it)
4. Open the .kdbx file with [KeyPass](https://keepass.info/download.html), using the master password from before and you can copy your passwords directly to the clipboard, or reveal them with the default hotkey **Ctrl + H**

Answer (score 15):

You can also recover database passwords. 
I found myself needing one a couple of times in the past. I am providing MacOS details here but the rest of the OS's are probably similar.

To recover these you need to go to the directory of the project where the database is setup, go inside the hidden .idea folder and search for the dataSources.xml file, in it you will find an uuid for each of the databases:

This UUID is what you need to search in the "Keychain Access" for.

Comment: I found that a database connection can be highlighted and its info copied using Cmd-C, then pasted into text file, which shows its uuid.  This avoids having to look for it in  dataSources.xml

Answer (score 2):

Having same problem, except I didn't set master password at all.

After research figure out, that password is lies in security.xml file, at .IntelliJIdea12/config/options filder. But it protected by AES ( at least seems so ).

-- edit --

Also see my comment below, where i've point to IDE source that handles password store and encryption

Comment: Thanks. The Intellij IDEA code is open source, so one should be able to figure out how to decrypt the passwords. I'll try to look into it.

Comment: I've found implementation of password store and encode\decode, but fail to figure out how to reverse process. All code related lays in com.intellij.ide.passwordSafe namespase. As example - api for read\write to password database is in com.intellij.ide.passwordSafe.impl.providers.masterKey.PasswordDatabase ( http://goo.gl/cbmFAU ). And encrypt\decrypt code is in com.intellij.ide.passwordSafe.impl.providers.EncryptionUtil ( http://goo.gl/0gIcBU )

Comment: The `EncryptionUtil` class seems to import classes only from the standard JAva libraries, so it should be possible to use it without compiling the entire IDEA codebase. The method for decrypting should be `public static byte[] decryptKey(byte[] password, byte[] encryptedKey)` (http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.jetbrains/intellij-idea/12.1.2/com/intellij/ide/passwordSafe/impl/providers/EncryptionUtil.java?av=f#148)

Comment: I'll try it when I get home

Comment: if you succeed - I will be immensely grateful for the solution.

Comment: I've put together a small utility here: https://github.com/corneliudascalu/intellij-decrypt. Feel free to adapt the code if you need.

Comment: Works like a charm after small adaptation, thanks! One note - your util does not accept empty master password. I was able to solve this by adding try-catch, but it was an ugly crunch.

Comment: Yeah, I realized that after putting the code on Github, but I didn't have the time to fix it. You can contribute your changes if you want.

Comment: It looks like no patches/pull requests were submitted for the empty master password issue. Anyway, set a password, and set it back to "" after recovery.

Comment: @CorneliuDascălu How to use that github tool to decrypt the master password for Windows?