# Android Studio where is Master Password stored?

Tags: android-studio

When you generate a APK in Android Studio you can secure the generation with a Master Password. Where in the filesystem is this password stored? I'm hoping I'm not committing this file in my project, i.e. and uploading it to Github:-)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The master password isn't actually stored, but it's used to encrypt the master password file, which lives in the **security.xml** file with your Android Studio preferences. That file contains encrypted versions of your keystore and key passwords ***if you check the "Remember Passwords" checkbox in the Generate Signed APK wizard***; if you don't tell it to remember passwords, nothing is stored.

Where that file lives depends on your platform, but in general on Windows it will be in `<User home>\.AndroidStudioPreview\config\security.xml`, `~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudioPreview/options/security.xml` on MacOS, and `~/.AndroidStudioPreview/config/security.xml` on Linux. See http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/project-and-ide-settings.html for more information on where preferences are stored for IntelliJ; it's essentially the same for Android Studio.

You can find a little more information on the file in a SO question about trying to decrypt the file contents if the master password is known: [Intellij IDEA - view saved password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21195321/intellij-idea-view-saved-password)

Comment: On my mac the file was here ./Library/Preferences/AndroidStudioPreview/options/security.xml

Comment: On Mac OS current path /Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio/options/security.xml

Comment: @Scott Barta, once we checked "Remember Passwords" can we undo it? I want to put password manually as before.

Comment: I am panicking right now because I forgot my master password. What do I do? Please help me!!

Answer (score 2):

For Android Studio version 1.0.2 on windows 7, the security.xml is located at 
.AndroidStudio\config\options\security.xml

Comment: This doesn't seem to add anything to the accepted answer.

Comment: Yes it does. Scott mentioned "AndroidStudioPreview", Stanley wrote "AndroidStudio" which is correct.

Comment: @StanleyWu I did not find the file named security.xml in my whole Android Studio 3.0 folder. Update the answer for new versions

Answer (score 2):

In my linux system this is where the security.xml file is located::

```
~/.AndroidStudio2.2/config/options/security.xml
```

Master passwords are encrypted (AES) and saved in security.xml file. It's location could change based on system and the version of android studio that you are using.
You can run the following command in command shell.

```
locate security.xml
```