# I Forgot Android Studio Master Password

Tags: android, android-studio, passwords

This might be a little bit silly but I forgot my master password. Even I also forgot when I set the master password.

Every time I want to generate signed `APK` the Android Studio always asks for master password. What I can do to get my master password again sir?

I also read the thread [on stackoverflow here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23548418/android-studio-where-is-master-password-stored/23549472#23549472) but it doesn't work.

Please help me with this one. I'll appreciate your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. You can create yourself a new password this time. [Read this](https://www.udacity.com/wiki/ud853/course_resources/creating-a-signed-apk) article to generate a signed apk with your new password.
2. Now , read this point super carefully, ***DO TICK THE BOX*** , that says ***"Remember password"***
   [image]

Comment: i have try to create a new keystore but still when i click next, the android studio ask me the master password. How to solve this sir?

Comment: Read the link to see how to reset the master password

Comment: @cafebabe1991 Update the link. It is broken.

Answer (score 18):

You can reset password

1. **File -> Setting ->** type **password** in search

[image]

2. click on **master password -> leave empty -> click ok** (disable password protection)
3. Now again click **master password ->click reset -> enter new password**

Answer (score 1):

just reset master password it will work fine dont bother about that