# Resetting Master password in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, keystore

I am sure this is a dumb question, but I cannot find the answer anywhere. I have just resetted my master password. My Key and Keystore passwords are still remembered, but when I try to build the APK, I get the error: "Failed to read key from store (jks file). Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect". What do I need to build my project again?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16891182/keytool-error-keystore-was-tampered-with-or-password-was-incorrect). It could happen because you are choosing the directory and not the keystore file.

Comment: I am unsure how the resetting affects the keys. Does it invalidate the jks file, thus having to put a backup file or create a new one?

Comment: Resetting Android Studio's master password will never affect keystore files(jks). The password you set is IDE specific which remembers all other passwords.

Comment: I guess I may be entering a wrong password. Thank you!

Comment: My pleasure. Also check out this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21195321/intellij-idea-view-saved-password#answer-21921620) if you want to decrypt and get your andorid studio's master password back.